# Localize Application icon for UK market and for USA market on iTunes

Tags: iphone, localization, icons, itunes

I'm trying to figure out a way of localizing the application icon (Icon.png) for the US Market and the UK market for my app I want a different type of vehicle picture for the uk rather than the US for instance.

This looks quite easy to do the info.plist and localize for English to French for instance but I couldn't figure out a way to do it for UK to USA.

In app it's easy just query the Locale but I've not idea how to do it for the application Icon which I can't control programatically

Thanks

Graham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepare two versions of app (with slight different names). One for USA store and one for UK store
Upload both the apps to app store and restrict your app to that particular iTunes store.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that and release an update ,so as to not annoying existing customers of the app into thinking its a scam to raise more sales :( thanks for the reply